# joining two variables in PHP line by line

Tags: php

I have two variables.

Ex:

```
Var 1

apple;orange;banana PHP_EOL
pear;orange;banana PHP_EOL
peach;orange;banana PHP_EOL
melon;orange;banana PHP_EOL

Var 2
$1 PHP_EOL
$2 PHP_EOL
$5 PHP_EOL
$6 PHP_EOL
```

I want to join them so the end of the first line of Var 1 combines with the first line of Var2

The result:

```
apple;orange;banana;$1 PHP_EOL
pear;orange;banana;$2 PHP_EOL
peach;orange;banana;$5 PHP_EOL
melon;orange;banana;$6 PHP_EOL
```

I have tried this but it doesnt seem to work:

```
$var1 = explode(PHP_EOL,$fruit);
$var2 = explode(PHP_EOL,$price);

foreach($hist_data1 as $var_h && $change_data1 as $var_c)
{

  $v1 = $var1['0'];
  $v2 = $var2['0'];

  $new_file = $new_file . $v1 . ';' . $v2;
} 

echo $new_file;
```

But I am not getting the result I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<?php
$fruit = 
'apple;orange;banana
pear;orange;banana
peach;orange;banana
melon;orange;banana';

$price = '$1
$2
$5
$6';

$var1 = explode("\r\n",$fruit);
$var2 = explode("\r\n",$price);
print_r($var1);
print_r($var2);
foreach($var1 as $key=>$val)
{
      echo $val.";".$var2[$key].PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
apple;orange;banana;$1
pear;orange;banana;$2
peach;orange;banana;$5
melon;orange;banana;$6
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/191057)**

Comment: $var1 = explode(PHP_EOL,$fruit);
$var2 = explode(PHP_EOL,$price);
foreach($var1 as $key=>$val)
{
      $new_file = $new_file . $val.";".$var2[$key].PHP_EOL;
}
 
 echo $new_file;
?>  
 worked for me. Thank you!